# Restrict bandwidth with DD-WRT

Tags: iptables, bandwidth, dd-wrt

I have DD-WRT installed on my router and I would like to be able to restrict the bandwidth both up and down on a certain IP or Mac address. I am happy to get my hands dirty and use console.

I am sure that iptables can do this? If so could someone show me a quick example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, unfortunately I haven't found a simple way to do this otherwise I would give you some examples; however, the `tc` command will do what you need.

Tc is a traffic shaping utility that is built into the Linux kernel. Be prepared, it isn't for the faint of heart. I recommend doing a good bit of reading about the queuing disciplines before starting.

At the least, this should give you somewhere to start:

http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Tc_command

**EDIT:**

From that page, this link claims to have a "simple" answer:

http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.ratelimit.single.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `tc` command to accomplish this. If you'd like to rate-limit a single host, there's a quick guide here:

[Rate limiting a single host or netmask](http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.ratelimit.single.html)

If you'd like a more comprehensive setup (for example, to guarantee prioritized traffic to VoIP), DD-WRT's supports setting up QoS rules directly via its user interface. Look here:

[Quality Of Service](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Quality_of_Service)

This link from the `tc` creators provides a great overview of traffic shaping using their tool, which is worth a read:

[The Ultimate Traffic Conditioner: Low Latency, Fast Up & Downloads](http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.cookbook.ultimate-tc.html)

Answer (score 1):

Something like [this](http://markmaunder.com/2011/01/26/how-to-reliably-limit-the-amount-of-bandwidth-your-room-mate-or-bad-office-colleague-uses/) for quick example:

```
tc qdisc del dev br0 root
tc qdisc add dev br0 root handle 1: cbq avpkt 1000 bandwidth 10mbit
tc class add dev br0 parent 1: classid 1:1 cbq rate 700kbit allot 1500 prio 5 bounded isolated
tc filter add dev br0 parent 1: protocol ip prio 16 u32 match ip dst 192.168.1.133 flowid 1:1
tc filter add dev br0 parent 1: protocol ip prio 16 u32 match ip src 192.168.1.133 flowid 1:1
```

Substitute **700kbit** for limit you want to enforce, and **192.168.1.133** for IP you want to limit. Note that **10mbit** in the first line should be near your real link speed for this to function best.

Enter it in ssh console for test. When you're happy with it, in dd-wrt put it under `Administration / Commands / Save Firewall` to have it start automatically on reboot / interface changes.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is by placing the device in the bulk class using QoS via the web GUI then rate limiting that entire class using a cron job.

http://hardwareinsights.com/wp/2011/04/28/optimizing-your-internet-usage-with-the-qos-functionality-of-dd-wrt/